# Difference betweeb Wamp, node JS and express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, wamp

I come ask my question here not because i did't found the answer but rather because i don't understand them...

Currently I try to do a website with HTML / CSS and basic JS but I need a database

And when I see different tutos in YouTube or other I always see Express, node...

Yes, I already use NodeJs but not Express, I only know him by name

And i'm lost, and i didn't know what to do to use mySQL with JS

I know Javascript is a front-end language and with NodeJS we can use it in back-end but...

In this case, with mySQL, what's difference between Node, Express and Wamp ?

All answer that i have is : *"Some of them are servers but not really a server, but more or less a server"

Yes, i didn't understand !

So can you please explain me what's three of them ?
Wamp simulate a locale server
But express too... ?
And node JS don't need to use a server... ?
If i use expressJS with Wamp will it be the same on a VPS ?
Please I need an explanation

Answer (score 0):

WAMP is an abbreviation for Windows+Apache+MySQL+PHP environment. It is also the name of a package that lets you easily install Apache, MySQL and PHP on a Windows machine. Apache is a powerful web server software, which you can still use in front of Node, but don't have to (as a beginner, ignoring Apache is fine). PHP is a serverside programming language, but you are already decided on using JavaScript/Node.js, so you don't need it. For your purposes, simply installing MySQL instead of WAMP makes more sense.

Node.js is a serverside runtime for JavaScript language. It is what lets you run your JavaScript code on a server computer, along with some essential libraries that extend JavaScript with functions that it does not have built-in, such as the ability to read files, or to accept incoming connections (like HTTP requests).

You could make a web server purely in Node.js, but it would be a lot of hard work. [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) is a framework (basically, a big library) you can install that already does a lot of that hard work for you, letting you focus on writing your web application's logic and not have to write low-level code that would make up the guts of your web application.

In the same way, you could theoretically write your own code to communicate with MySQL, but the mysql library exists so you wouldn't have to.

So if you are making a serverside JavaScript web application, you would typically start with installing MySQL and Node.js, then use `npm` (Node.js package management tool) to install Express.js and mysql packages. Apache is optional, so don't worry about it now; PHP is entirely superfluous.

Comment: Okay, I understand a little better
I already used PHP, Node, JS, WAMP, all of this is not new to me so technically I shouldn't have a problem to write this back-end JS app.
But something that i don't understand (yeah... again...) to run nodeJS and and especially his package "mysql" i need to use express to ? Or i can do everything with WAMP ?